# .htaccess redirect my site gives internal error

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying for the first time to make a .htaccess file. For at start I would like to make a redirect, so if a person writes:

> https://example.com/robots.txt

the person will be redirected to

> https://example.com

I made the file, and added the following code:

```
Redirect 301 https://example.com/robots.txt/ https://example.com/index.php
```

I also tried with:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/bonus https://example.com/robots.txt
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ https://example.com/
```

which both resulted in my site got internal error. So how is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure why you would want to direct away from your `robots.txt` file as this could stop search engine crawlers from accessing the file... but you can do it using this:

```
Redirect 301 /robots.txt /index.php
```

or, try this:

```
Redirect 301 /robots.txt https://www.example.com/
```

To then to get rid of `www` use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ah okay I did not know that, so thanks for the information :-) But if if fx wanted to redirect my image folder I could do like you do here? I just read that it is also possible to make some URL more "good looking" with .htaccess. Is that correct?

Comment: No problem. Yes, you could indeed. You're also correct about being able to use `.htaccess` to make your URLs more 'pretty' and user friendly. Its quite simple and can be done by using a `RewriteRule`

Comment: Thank you a lot for that